# problem with jpa inbound channel adapter output

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

```
@Bean
public JpaPollingChannelAdapter reimStgResponseJpaInboundAdapter() {
    return Jpa
            .inboundAdapter(entityManager)
            .nativeQuery(responseQueryString)
            //.expectSingleResult(true)
            .get(); 
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow reimFeedbackHandle() {
    return IntegrationFlows
                    .from("reimFeedbackChannel")
                    .handle(msg -> {
                        try {
                            dctmHandler.handleReIMFeedback(msg);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }})
                    .get(); 
}
```

the `.expectSingleResult(true)` return exception that 1 result was expected.

The native query is `String responseQueryString = "select * from RMS16DEV.TSC_IM_DOC_HEAD_TEMP where error_ind is not null"`;

The msg from inbound adapter is an array list and I am not able to cast it to the correct entity. 
What is the type that is returned by jpa inbound adapter to the channel?

```
public void handleReIMFeedback(Message<?> reimStgRowMsg) throws Exception {
    List<TSC_IM_DOC_HEAD_TEMP> list = (List<TSC_IM_DOC_HEAD_TEMP>) reimStgRowMsg.getPayload(); 
    System.out.println( (list.get(0)));
}
```

gives me:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class java.util.List ([Ljava.lang.Object; and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at tesco.finance.gss.dctmreim.jpa.handlers.DctmHandlers.handleReIMFeedback(DctmHandlers.java:28)
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code fixed the issue:

```
@Bean
public JpaPollingChannelAdapter reimStgResponseJpaInboundAdapter() {
    return Jpa
            .inboundAdapter(entityManager)
            .nativeQuery(responseQueryString)
            .expectSingleResult(true)
            .entityClass(TSC_IM_DOC_HEAD_TEMP.class)
            .get(); 
}
```